Bulk redirect Wordpress website URLs without redirect chain
I have a multilingual website in WordPress. It has IT and EN versions, and I want to change its default language to EN.
For SEO, I want to redirect all of the old URLs to new ones:
site.com/*  to site.com/it/* (Except the main page)
site.com/en/* to site.com/*
I want to add redirect rules in the .htaccess file. I tried too many times, and all of the codes caused a redirect chain. For example:
`RewriteEngine On

# Redirect from /en/* to /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^en(/.*)?$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect all other requests to /it/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en(/.*)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/it(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /it/$1 [R=301,L]

# Ensure no loop occurs by fixing /it/index.php redirection
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/it/index.php$
RewriteRule ^it/index.php$ /it/ [R=301,L]`


Would you please help me?

I’m afraid that just doesn’t make much sense. The /* URLs continue to exist, you’re not deprecating them. Just their content changes. When somebody requests the /* URLs, you don’t know what they intend to see; the English or Italian version. So it makes no sense to redirect one to the other.

URLs are completely different in each language. For example:
site.com/contact in English
site.com/it/contatto/ in Italian

Well, then you can redirect those individual URLs by listing them out, but not /* in general.
